# Missing candle stick on the GOOG stock market chart

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-markets, yahoo-finance, day-trading

On the 14th of February 2020 at 12.30 noon, there is no 1-minute candle stick on the GOOG stock market chart. It jumps directly from 12.29 to 12.31

I check on [Yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/GOOG#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%3D) and TD Ameritrade. Both do not show any candle on that specific minute. What happened? Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

- There was a trading halt in GOOG shares at that time
- Data providers have screwed up

Since there is no GOOG trading halt listed on the Nasdaq Trading Halt page, one can only assume that this is a data provider issue.  One could also reach the same conclusion by looking at Time & Sales.